# Get Serilog settings from appsettings in Program.cs

Tags: c#, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0

I am creating a Windows Service using a .Net Core 6 Worker project.

I have added Setilog which is working, and I have settings in appsettings.json. However, I would like to write to the log file when starting and stopping the service. I have the following code in **program.cs**, which seems to work, but this does not make use of the settings in appsettings.json. Is it possible to get the settings from appsettings.json instead of adding them to this initial Serilog setup?

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Information()
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.File("./logs/log-.txt", rollingInterval:RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateBootstrapLogger();

try
{
    Log.Information("Starting the Service");

    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .UseSerilog()
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        })
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
    return;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "There was a problem starting the service");
    return;
}
finally
{
    Log.Information("Service successfully stopped");
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you found the article on bootstrap logging but only used half of the code. You still need to configure and register Bootstrap for normal logging

Answer (score 3):

This looks like part of the code used for two-stage initialization. `CreateBootstrapLogger()` is used to create a logger that can be used only until .NET Core's logging infrastructure is configured and functional.

```
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Events;

public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateBootstrapLogger();
```

The [Two-stage initialization](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#two-stage-initialization) docs show how to read settings using `ReadFrom.Configuration` in the main logger configuration :

```
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
                
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                
                .ReadFrom.Services(services)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: OK, so does that mean that I have to configure the logger twice (effectively), once how I have it at the top of program.cs and then in appsettings.json which will be read by .UserSerilog() (as you have it above)? Edit: I want the inital startup logging to go to the same file, not the console. Using just (UseSerilog() seems to work for that.

Comment: Do you *need* the bootstrap logger? It's *your* code that uses two-stage initialization by calling `CreateBootstrapLogger`.  If you don't want that, don't create the logger like this in the first place. Use only the configuration specified in `UseSerilog`

Comment: Besides, the doc example clearly shows the loggers aren't the same. The bootstrap logger only needs to log something in case the application fails to start, eg because it *couldn't* read the configuration. It doesn't have to log to the same sinks the proper logger does

Comment: It's probably me that's confused! I want to send all logging to a text file, I expected the Serilog config to be in appsettings. So is it fine to configure Serilog in Program.cs (as I have) and not call CreateBootstrapLogger, and not have Serilog settings in appsettings?

Comment: Do you want to use the config settings or not? If so, use `UseSerilog(...ReadFrom)`. You don't have to create the global logger. `Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()` isn't necessary. The second snippet creates a Serilog logger using the config settings and connects it to .NET Core's `ILogger`

Comment: You aren't reading the logger settings from `appsettings.json`, you're reading them from the Configuration subsystem. This means that all configured sources are used, including environment variables and command-line options. If an environment variable or CLI parameter matches a Serilog setting, it will be used instead of whatever is in `appsettings.json`. If an `appsettings.Production.json` file exists, it will override the root file

Comment: So how would the "Log." commands work in Program.cs? Can you revise my original Program.cs code so that it doesn't create the global logger, uses the settings from appsettings and still has the 3 Log commands in Program.cs?